# Reverse lists in list of lists prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I want to reverse each list from a list of lists. 
I have something which looks like:

```
[[a,b],[],[c,d,e],[],[],[f,g]]
```

What I want is to read through the list of lists and reverse each list and get this result:

```
[[b,a],[],[e,d,c],[],[],[g,f]]
```

I already have a reverse function:

```
reverse(L, R) :- reverse(L, [], R).
reverse([], R, R).
reverse([H|T], A, R) :- reverse(T, [H|A], R).
```

How can I manage to read through the list?

Will a recursive function like this one work ?

```
reverseLL([H|T], L) :-
   reverse(H,NH),
   reverseLL([T],[NH|L]).

reverseLL([],L).
```

Comment: `maplist(reverse, L, R)`

Comment: Thank you ! I didn't know maplist even existed for prolog

Answer (score 1):

```
reverseInList([],[]).
reverseInList([H|Ts],[H1|R]):-
    reverse(H,H1),
    reverseInList(Ts,R).
```

This works by recursing over the list and using the library function 'reverse/2' to reverse each sublist.